# Why do my Unit tests fail because my project has realm objects?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, realm

My iOS app uses Realm. It has Realm subclasses like `MyRealmClass`.

When I try to run any unit test in my workspace, I get the following error:
"RLMObject subclasses with the same name cannot be included twice in the same target. Please make sure 'MyRealmClass' is only linked once to your current target."

What I tried:
 * I tried removing 'MyRealmClass' from the Test target. That does not work. When I do that the code won't compile anymore because the code is dependent on 'MyRealmClass'

Comment: How are you importing your app module in your test?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have a cocoapod setup

Comment: If you want to test anything in your app you should import the app target using `@import MyApp` in your unit test files. That will expose all `internal` and `public` objects in your app target to your unit tests. (This is completely unrelated to cocoapods)

Comment: I already have @testable import MyApp

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I mistyped when I wrote `@import`. If the realm classes are part of the app target and you have `@testable import XXX` in your test file your realm classes should be available. Could you maybe update the question with the test code that's causing problems is you remove the realm classes from the test target, and the exact error message you get?

Comment: I am not trying to make the realm classes available. I am trying to avoid this error: "RLMObject subclasses with the same name cannot be included twice in the same target."

Comment: Right, and you said that you have your subclasses in your test and app target but run into problems when you remove your class from the test target. If you're not using your class in the test target it seems weird that that would cause an error.

Comment: I do not. MyRealmClass is defined in the app target. I am just trying to write a unit test that tests a different file in the app target. Agree that it is weird that's why I am asking here

Comment: @gregm Sounds like you added `MyRealmClass` to your Test Target. Look at Target Membership. If your Test is checked, uncheck it.

Comment: Can you share your test class and the exact error you're getting when you remove the realm subclass from the test target

Comment: MyRealmClass is added to my TestTarget. When it is not added, then xcode cannot compile because there is other code that depends on it.

Comment: @gregm `@import` imports everything for you. You don' want to manually add any App files to your Test Target.

Comment: Your app code should indeed only be in your app target and your test code should only be in your test target. Sounds like that could be what's going wrong here

Comment: I removed all the app files from the test project. Then I imported the project into the test file. The code still has the same exception about duplicate Realm files when the code does Realm()